# Magento Duplicate entry in `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` error on product save

Tags: magento, exception, magento-1.9

I have a product with `Tier Price` enabled. When I load that product and try to update, Magento throws exception.

Here is my code.

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(779);
try {
    $_product->setData('backorder_limit', '10');
    $_product->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Above code prints below exception

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '779-1-0-5.0000-0' for key 'E8AB433B9ACB00343ABB312AD2FAB087', query
>   was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` (`entity_id`,
>   `all_groups`, `customer_group_id`, `qty`, `value`, `website_id`)
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

When I remove Tier Price, above code works fine. I tried reindexing and cleared Cache but no success.

I am clueless about the error, so I am here to ask you guys if someone know what is the issue and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes `$product->save()` throws this error.

To prevent this, try using `$product->getResource()->save($product)`.

I hope it will to for you.

**EDIT :** This assuming you set on top of your script.

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```